# Simple DOM PHP adding wildcard in URL of file_get_html

Tags: php, url, wildcard

I'm trying to catch a URL that has a variable ending:

$html = file_get_html(http://example.com/$date-string then VARIABLE STUFF HERE"

I've been searching for a few hours now and can not find a solution.  Thought maybe using regular expression but that seems to be for matching.  Can't recall all the various things I've tried but latest is:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$year = date('Y');
$var = /^string/;
$url = "/https:\/\/example.com\/podcasts\/audio\/$date-&var";
$html = file_get_html($url)
```

;

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Have `file_get_html` somehow match an url you don't know exactly?

Comment: yes, I know the url up to a point, after that, it can be changed.  Typically gets changed with for additional (constant) characters.

Comment: also, given what I do know, it is unique (i.e. up to and including the string)
That "for additional" in previous comment should be "four additional"

Comment: That is not possible. `file_get_html` needs an exact url as a parameter, it can't just magically try and guess the rest, nor can it know what urls exist for that site in order to try and match a wildcard.

Comment: Then, I need to make it an "if" statement (I think), if this or that url, whichever one exists because only one of the two will exist.  Thanks.